# CoffeeScript parse error - Unexpected "(" - But there's no "(" in the code

Tags: coffeescript

Here's the original code:

```
res.write JSON.stringify {"#{result.statusCode}": "OK"}
```

and here's the error that both the CoffeeScript linter in SublimeText 2 and the "Try CoffeeScript" interpreter on the CoffeeScript site give me:

```
PARSE ERROR ON LINE 1: UNEXPECTED '('
```

Obviously there's no open parens in the code, so I don't understand the error. Is it a bug in the CoffeeScript parser?

The smallest line of code that does this seems to be something like this:

```
{"#{a}": ""}
```

I'm assuming that string interpolation in an object's key is valid, but I don't know for sure.

EDIT:
After some investigation it seems that it's not valid to do the string interpolation in the key because the resulting JavaScript would be invalid.

This:

```
{"#{a}": "stuff}
```

would translate to something like:

```
{ "" + a: "stuff"}
```

which isn't valid.

But can someone explain why the error message it gives me is so wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm assuming that string interpolation in an object's key is valid, but I don't know for sure.

Unfortunately it's not.

You'll have to do something like

```
(json = {})[result.statusCode] = 'OK'
res.write JSON.stringify json
```

or if you want a one-liner

```
res.write (-> ((json = {})[result.statusCode] = 'OK') and JSON.stringify json)()
```

As for the misleading error, CoffeeScript is trying to translate your `{"#{a}": ''}` into `{("" + a): ""}` which is not valid JavaScript. CoffeeScript is throwing the error at that left paren.

Comment: Thanks. I was fooling around and realized that I was wrong on this. I still don't understand why it claims there's a "(" in my code. If no one can answer that I'll just accept this as the answer.

Comment: I added to my answer, check it out.

Comment: Interesting. So CoffeeScript is throwing the error *after* it's compiled to JavaScript?

Comment: I can't say for sure as I haven't really dived into the parser code, but at some point the translated code is checked for JavaScript syntax correctness. To my knowledge it's impossible to compile CoffeeScript into JavaScript that would contain a syntax error.